# C++ writing a program that accepts a series of numbers, press enter then the sum and total will be calculated

Tags: c++, input, sum, numbers, average

I am trying to develop a code that accepts input numbers from user then they would press enter and the numbers input the average will be found. My issue is line 14 which says

```
error: primary-expression before ')' token
```

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int num, sum, count;
    
float average;
    
sum=0;
    
count=0;
   
cout<<"Enter a number or Press Enter to quit:";
  
 cin>>num;

    while (num!=);
    sum+=float(num)
    count+ =1
    num= input("Enter a number or Press Enter to quit:")
    cout>>"Sum: "+str(sum);
    cout>>"Average: "+str(sum/count));
    cin>>"The sum is", sum;
    cin>>"The average is, average";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please copy your code to the clipboard and paste that text into your question.

Comment: I am new to both the stack overflow platform and programming, however I just did so. Could you please assist?

Comment: I was going to clean that up and found that you have un-compilable code. And your original question is gone.

Comment: What is the extra `)` doing here? `cout>>"Average: "+str(sum/count));` Also, where is the `str` function defined? It's not in the code you've shown. `while (num!=);` looks really wrong too. What is that supposed to do?

Comment: You made a classic mistake of writing too much code without testing it in between. We can list all the typos you've made like compiler does, but my suggestion would be to discard this code and start again, this time writing only one line of code at a time, compiling that code and (if possible) testing if does exactly what you want it.

Comment: Did you actually copy some lines from Python? `input` is not a standard function in C++, and lack of semicolons after several lines suggests Python origin.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Good catch. That's probably where the `str` function came from too. :)

Comment: I was watching videos on YouTube trying to understand hence the many errors. Thank you guys for your advices. I will discard of it and start over while watching over the videos. Thank you for your feedbacks thus far.

Comment: `while (num!=);` the whole loop ends at the `;` that is provided you fix what is in the conditional part ()

Comment: Hi guys, Thank for the feedback. I started from scratch and figured it out. I would like to post my answer but I'm not sure how to on the platform. Thanks again!

Comment: @DarrkenSkky There should be a big box just below here where with a `Post Your Answer` button.

Comment: Thank you, I posted it. It ran however i still have a slight issue with the enter to exit using  getchar

Answer (score 0):

#include 
using namespace std;

```
int main ()

{
int num, sum,c,count, loop_num;
float average;
sum=0;
count=0;
loop_num=0;


cout<<"Enter the series of numbers:" <<endl;


while (count<1)
{
    cin>> num;
    sum=sum+num;
    loop_num++;


    c= getchar();
    if (c=='\n'){
        count=1;}
}

 average=sum/(double)loop_num;
cout<<"The sum of your numbers is:"<<sum<<endl;
cout<<"The average of your numbers is: "<<average;


return 0;
```

}